# Is there any way to differentiate UV light from visible or IR light?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, wavelength, sensor

I'm working on a small sensor system that responds to only UV light and I wanted to know that is there any way to differentiate between UV light and the rest of the spectrum like using lens if so then what kind of lens to be used etc. Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Do you have a single UV wavelength you'd like to detect, or are you interested in the UV spectrum?

Comment: only 315nm wavelength is required for the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

Use a prism to disperse the light by wavelength, and then just put the sensor where the UV part of the spectrum falls, or physically block out the wavelengths that you don't want.

Comment: Or a diffraction grating. One could use a Compact Disk. Transmission gratings are more convenient. With a recordable CD it is easiest to remove the metallic layer. (But the plastic will absorb the shortest wavelengths.)

Answer (score 1):

Buy a bandpass filter, which transmits around 315nm. A bandpass filter is a "glass plate", which absorb "all" wavelength except some within a certain wavelength range. Look at the transmission spectrum of the bandpass filer and check whether or not this is acceptable.